# Did Hamas & PIJ manage to smuggle in substantial numbers of fully assembled rockets after 2014?

Tags: military, gaza, hamas, egypt, smuggling

In 2014, the IDF [gave](https://www.idf.il/en/mini-sites/the-hamas-terrorist-organization/special-report-the-deadly-rocket-arsenal-of-hamas/) a breakdown of their estimates of the Hamas rocket arsenal. Interestingly, in the 45km range rockets, the whole-piece smuggled ones dominated, but in the 75km range, it was actually the locally maade that were the majority.

> Medium range (up to 45 km)
>
> - Approx. 200 units of self-produced improved Grad rockets (45 km)
> - Approx. 1,000 units of smuggled improved Grad rockets (45 km)
>
> Medium-Long range (up to 80 km)
>
> - Over 400 units of self-produced medium range rockets

The latter, i.e. the M-75, was apparently made in Gaza based on Iranian Fajr-5 schematics (and probably other help). The situation was fairly similar for the PIJ: 200/600 self-produced/smuggled 45-km Grads and some 100 self-produced 80-km rockets.

I'm curious if there's an update of their arsenal for the 2020s available somewhere, or a direct answer to the following:

Was the change in Egyptian governance (end of the brief Arab Spring there) effective in curbing more fully-assembled rocket imports for Hamas & PIJ? I.e. did they have to rely more on self-made stuff later on?